# Parsing PHP Menu System 3d Array. Modification to allow me to specify Parent and return Child Pages

Tags: php, menu, multidimensional-array, recursive-query

I have built an array which holds a website menu system:

---

```
$menu = array(
    'Page_1' => array(
        'display' => 'Page 1'
    ),
    'Page_2' => array(
        'display' => 'Page 2',
        'sub' => array(
            'Sub_Page_1' => array(
                'display' => 'Sub Page 1'
            )
        )
    ),
    'Page_3' => array(
        'display' => 'Page 3',
        'sub' => array(
            'Sub_Page_2' => array(
                'display' => 'Sub Page 2'
            ),
            'Sub_Page_3' => array(
                'display' => 'Sub Page 3'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

---

I am using the following function to parse and output the menu system as a nested unordered list.

---

```
function Build_Menu($menu_array,$is_sub){

    $attr = (!$is_sub) ? ' class="menu"' : ' class="submenu"';
    $menu = "<ul$attr>";

    foreach($menu_array as $id => $properties){

        foreach($properties as $key => $val){

            if(is_array($val)){
                $sub = Build_Menu($val,TRUE);
            }
            else{
                $sub = NULL;
                $$key = $val;
            }
        }

        $menu .= '<li><a href="#">'.$display.'</a>'.$sub.'</li>';

        unset($url, $display, $sub);

    }

    return $menu . "</ul>";

}
```

---

This works fine and generates a list like this:

```
Page 1
Page 2
    Sub Page 1
Page 3
    Sub Page 2
    Sub Page 3
```

---

Where I am getting stuck is that I am now looking to modify the function so that I can pass in a parent page and just return the child pages of that parent.

Something like:

function Build_Menu($menu_array,$is_sub,'Page 2'){
    ...
}

which would generate the following output:

```
Page 2
    Sub Page 1
```

or

function Build_Menu($menu_array,$is_sub,'Page 3'){
    ...
}

which would generate:

```
Page 3
    Sub Page 2
    Sub Page 3
```

---

The important thing is that the function remains recursive so that no matter how many sub levels their are, they will be output as part of the function. The plan is that the "display" value for each page will be the unique identifier.

Any help would be most appreciated as I have been going round in circles for hours with this!

Many thanks, James.

Answer (score 0):

this looks a bit like re-inventing the wheel. You may want to use your search engine of choice to look for "php tree structure" or have a look at heaps and double linked lists in SPL. http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php

Answer (score 0):

Couldn’t you do it like this?

```
function Build_Sub_Menu($menu, $key) {
   return Build_Menu(array($menu[$key]), false);
}

echo Build_Sub_Menu($menu, 'Page_2');
```

Of course you could do the same inside `Build_Menu`, but I think another function is easier to understand and maintain.

It's up to you validate if `$key` exists in `$menu`.

Comment: That works great for one level from the top, thanks. It falls down when I get to a menu system with more levels.  e.g.

    Page 1
    Page 2
        Sub Page 1
    Page 3
        Sub Page 2
        Sub Page 3
            Sub Page 4
            Sub Page 5
   
Build_Sub_Menu($menu, 'Sub_Page_3');